# How do I use a mailto link in Text() in swift 5, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, mailto

There are dozens of Stackoverflow answers for mailto links in Swift 5.

The consensus look like this

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:jon.doe@mail.com")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

But how do I actually use this code? Ideally in an alert, but at least a general Text element

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenu: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    // What do I put here
    var emailLink:UIApplication {
        let url = URL(string: "mailto:jon.doe@mail.com")!
        return UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
    
    // To make it work in here
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: .zero, content: {
            Text(
                "Here is an email link \(emailLink)"
            )
            
            Button(action: {
                showAlert = true
            }) {
                Text("MENU")
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Title Here"),
                    message: Text(
                        "Need Help, \(emailLink)"
                    )
                )
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without an Alert, based on the suggestive comment of [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9607863/george) this works:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(
        "Here is an email link "
    )
            
    Link("jon.doe@mail.com", destination: URL(string: "mailto:jon.doe@mail.com")!)
```

Comment: you commented saying you preferred it in an alert " Ideally in an alert".

Comment: post an answer that works with alert and I'll mark it

Comment: it does work with alert, it uses a Button to openURL for mailto when you select the email button in the alert. Mailto doesn't work in the simulator, hence no mail app. I'm using something similar in my application for email support.

Comment: Im unable to post a screenshot as a comment, the code you posted results in a view error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '() -> Alert'`

Comment: compiles just fine, I just copied and pasted the exact code from the site back to a new project. What's the error then? Please update your answer with the updated code you are using.

Comment: can you update your question with the code you are now using.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's working for you, unfortunately It's not compiling for me and therefore I cannot mark it as working for me. https://imgur.com/a/Nf44maK

Comment: which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment` var `openURL` for this, documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openurl).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    @State var alert: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                alert.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Label("Email", systemImage: "envelope.fill")
            })
        }
        .alert("Contact", isPresented: $alert, actions: {
            Button(action: {
                mailto("jon.doe@mail.com")
            }, label: {
                Label("Email", systemImage: "envelope.fill")
            })
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
        })
    }
    
    func mailto(_ email: String) {
        let mailto = "mailto:\(email)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
        print(mailto ?? "")
        if let url = URL(string: mailto!) {
            openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: alert]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was unable to get the above code to work, after removing the hstack  which was mistakely getting the alert, instead of the button, I was still getting errors about the alert conforming to Text.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, I'm getting `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '() -> Alert'` with the above code